# Return and Remove Element from HTML String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm passing HTML back to an ajax call. In the HTML I want to strip out an element and store its HTML in a variable. I've tried:

```
request.success(function(results){
    var timer = $(results).find('#timer').html();   // returns undefined

    var timer = $('#timer', results);       // returns element but not content
    results = $(results).remove('#timer');  // doesn't remove element
    console.log(timer);
});
```

Do I need to run a regex search on the element itself? That could get extensive.

If I console log my HTML (results) I end up with:

```
e.fn.init[11]
    0: div#timer
    1: text
    2: comment
    3: text
    4: div.pagination.top
    5: text
    6: comment
    7: text
    8: div#postContainer
    9: text
    10: comment
    length: 11
    __proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: `$(results).find('#timer').html()` should work. Are you sure that `#timer` is in the HTML, and there's only one in there, and it's got some content?

Comment: 100% - if I `$('#content').html(results)` it shows up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit

`results` appear to be `DOM` elements, not jquery objects, `index`ed starting at `0`. Based on what console returned, should be able to access any of the `results` items based on their respective index, i.e.g., `$(results).get(4)` should return `div.pagination.top`

get `#timer` `html`

```
   var timer = $(results).get(0);
   timerContents = timer.innerHTML;
```

remove `#timer` from `results`

```
   var result = $.makeArray( results ); 
   result.splice(0, 1);
```

Comment: That's not necessarily universal - It does work but though. Can you spin that to work for any element? Also I would need to then remove it from the `results` html.

Comment: @SparoHawk if I change `innerHTML` to `.html()` I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'`

Comment: @Howdy_McGee may need to move `timer` to `index > 0` to become `child`

Comment: @guest271314 You are right, I forgot jQuery's `.get()` returns the DOM object instead of a jQuery object. I would change the code from `get()` to `eq()` instead then: `var timer = $(results).eq(0).html()`.

Comment: That works, and thanks for the help. I feel like the real problem, which is why the find / html wasn't working was because, as you said it needed to be a child of something. I put it inside the post container and I was wable to use find / html / remove functions just fine.